# SDL Toggle Text Visibility?

Tags: sdl

Im displaying text on the SDL screen, pertaining to the animation eg. the position of the moving sheep. I want to include an option that allows me to hide the text when a certain key is pressed on the keyboard. Is there an easy function to do this that Im not aware of?  Or if not, how would you go about it?

Comment: I was expecting a lot of answers by now :( Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

SDL is a pretty low level library, even the text display is not done by SDL but an auxiliary library such as SDL_ttf.

In the off-chance you're using SDL_ttf, it has a function called TTF_OpenFont [which can be used to swap font sizes](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2003-April/034944.html), so calling the rendering function can't draw any pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to decide not to render the text by reading a flag set when the key event happens. In my SDL projects i have one method rendering all graphics, which is called for every frame of execution. This is where i would add the conditional text rendering as well. Depending on the general design of your project this might not help at all i suppose :)